# update my table and insert new column in mysql using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need the syantax for inserting new column in existing table

```
client.query('ALTER TABLE login ADD'+'code VARCHAR(255)',function(err,result){
    if(err){
        console.log("ERROR:"+err.message);
    }
    else{
        console.log("new column added");
    }
});
```

it showing me error just need proper sytanx thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the query

```
      ALTER table login add column (code varchar(255));
```